# Highlight different text in jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

These are the following things i want to know:

I want to highlight different text in jtextarea by selecting them by mouse.
I also want to get all the highlighted text later.
I also want to know how to remove particular highlighted line.

What code can i use ?

Comment: *"What code can i use ?"*  [Reading the fine manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) should answer all your questions.  Note that SO is not your personal help desk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is all covered in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) & [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I asked this question when I was 14 years old. After 5 years I realize the question was useless and you were right, everything is on the DOC.
But you need to remember 14 years old has no one to guide, 5 years back I hardly had access to the internet. My teacher and family know nothing about coding.
Putting down vote and closing it demotivated me.
I hope you understand and be polite with the new generation coming to this coding world :)

Comment: Slight clarification, yes, I *did* vote to close the question. But the community has decided most questions cannot be closed based on one person's vote, it usually takes three.

Comment: Yeah! @AndrewThompson, but you got the point. We can be a little bit polite with the newbie :)
Anyway, I am already banned from SO because of my childhood _karma_ and in no way I can improve these questions to get unban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Highlighter`:

```
Highlighter hl = textArea.getHighlighter();
```

Read the API for the methods that allow you add, remove and display the highlights.